# Capture 50MP image on Samsung S22 with Camera2

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-camera2

How to capture 50mp images using Camera2API on Samsung S22?

In the native camera it shows an option to capture 3:4 50MP images as shown in the print taken from the Samsung Camera APP

[image]

But in Camera2, retrieving the available output sizes for different ImageFormat, the maximum resolution is 4080x3060

```
StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
Size[] sizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG); // Tried with RAW, JPEG and YUV
for (int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
    Size size = sizes[i];
    Log.d(TAG, " Width : " + size.getWidth() + " Height : " + size.getHeight());
}
```

How can I access the 50MP resolution (6120 x 8160) programmatically using Camera2API?

Comment: Manufacturers do not have to allow third-party apps to do everything that their built-in camera apps do.

Comment: Generally high resolution capture are done through camera sensor/Id which is not exposed to 3rd party app.